# Count numbers of JSON objects

Tags: php, json

After searching many hours I'm posting this question. I have a variable called `$responses` which outputs the encoded JSON objects as follows.

```
[
 {
    "notification_id": 4936,
    "notification_title": "Bridge construction",
    "notification_category": "Activities of extraterritorial organizations",
    "notification_posted_date": "19/09/16",
    "notification_time_left": "2016/10/11 12:45:00",
    "notification_by_company": "The Media Company"
 }
]
```

There are more than one objects and I'm trying to count the number as well using the code below.

```
echo json_encode($responses);   
echo count($responses);
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. I also tried this:

```
$JsonDecode = json_decode($responses, true);    
echo $JsonDecode;
```

The main issues are printing JSON and getting the count of objects. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: IN second code you forgot about `count`

Comment: can you provide whole json ?

Comment: that's the complete JSON response so far but off course it objects can be decreases and increased at the same time, due to word limit i can't post complete json response

[
    {
        "notification_id": 4936,
        "notification_title": "Bridge construction",
        "notification_category": "Activities of extraterritorial organizations and bodies",
        "notification_posted_date": "19/09/16",
        "notification_time_left": "2016/10/11 12:45:00",
        "notification_by_company": "The Media Company"
    }
]

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments. Please  [edit] that JSON into your question.

Comment: your json need single quote ' <- [ '   {"a":"2" }  '    ] @ZeeshanKhalid

Answer (score 0):

That json string represents an array containing one (maybe more) object(s).

So to count the properties of each object you could do something like this

```
$s = '[
 {
    "notification_id": 4936,
    "notification_title": "Bridge construction",
    "notification_category": "Activities of extraterritorial organizations",
    "notification_posted_date": "19/09/16",
    "notification_time_left": "2016/10/11 12:45:00",
    "notification_by_company": "The Media Company"
 }
]';

// Note using json_decode to convert a JSON string to its PHP equiv data type
$j = json_decode($s);   

echo 'The number of objects in the array is ' . count($j) . '<br>';

foreach ($j as $inx => $obj) {
    // count
    echo "Object $inx has " . count((array)$obj) . ' Properties<br>';
}
```

Result is

```
The number of objects in the array is 1<br>
Object 0 has 6 Properties<br>
```

I hope I correctly understood what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

If the `$responses` follows `{...},{...}....` then you could try

```
$explode = explode( '},{', $responses );
$count = count( $explode );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but unfortunately it didn't work 

               $explode = explode( '},{', $responses );
  $count = count( $explode );
  
  echo $count;

it returns 0 , so you think it can be solved any other way ?